# ggplot facet grid within a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, facet-grid

Consider data that looks like this

```
fitem<-rep(rep(1:16,each=3),2)
fsubs<-factor(rep(rep(paste('sub',1:3,sep=''),16),2))
ftime<-factor(as.character(rep(c('a','b'),each=48)))
fcounts<-as.numeric(round(runif(96,1,10)))
fdf<-data.frame(fsubs,fitem,fcounts,ftime)


head(df)

  fsubs fitem fcounts ftime
1  sub1     1       8     a
2  sub2     1      10     a
3  sub3     1       4     a
4  sub1     2       4     a
5  sub2     2       1     a
6  sub3     2       6     a
```

I would like to plot a facet grid that shows the counts for the two time points ('a','b'), subject-wise. I can't seem to figure out how to plot this in ggplot

here is my ugly attempt to do it

```
fdf_counts<-data.frame()
for (i in unique(fdf$fsubs)){
  fdf_counts<-append(fdf_counts,cbind(fdf%>%filter(fsubs==i,ftime=='a')%>%dplyr::select(fcounts),
                        fdf%>%filter(fsubs==i,ftime=='b')%>%dplyr::select(fcounts)))

fdf_counts<-data.frame(fdf_counts)
}

s1<-ggplot(fdf_counts,aes(x=fcounts,y=fcounts.1))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method='lm')+labs(x='a',y='b',title='sub1')
s2<-ggplot(fdf_counts,aes(x=fcounts.2,y=fcounts.3))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method='lm')+labs(x='a',y='b',title='sub2')
s3<-ggplot(fdf_counts,aes(x=fcounts.4,y=fcounts.5))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method='lm')+labs(x='a',y='b',title='sub3')



plot_grid(s1,s2,s3)#from 'cowplot' package
```

[image]

How can I do this with using the original `fdf` data.frame? Especially as the # of subs increase

Or for example if I wanted to plot one scatter plot across all of the subs with fcounts against eachother with ftime(a) as x axis and ftime(b) as y axis?

Comment: What are the two time points?

Comment: the time points are factors 'a', 'b', sorry if that was unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `merge` solution with data frame by itself on *fsubs* and *fitem* (being sequential number of items per *fsubs* and *ftime* grouping). This approach allows you to keep your long, [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) format which is ideal format for `ggplot` since you can then `facet_grid` using *fsubs* without iteration.

```
mdf <- merge(subset(fdf, ftime=="a"), 
             subset(fdf, ftime=="b"), 
             by=c("fsubs", "fitem"), 
             suffixes=c("", "_"))

ggplot(mdf, aes(x=fcounts, y=fcounts_)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  labs(x='a', y='b') + 
  facet_grid(~fsubs)
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Very elegant and still maintains tidy data format.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

fitem<-rep(rep(1:16,each=3),2)
fsubs<-factor(rep(rep(paste('sub',1:3,sep=''),16),2))
ftime<-factor(as.character(rep(c('a','b'),each=48)))
fcounts<-as.numeric(round(runif(96,1,10)))
fdf<-tibble(fsubs,fitem,fcounts,ftime)


fdf <- fdf %>%
  group_by(ftime) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = fcounts,
              names_from = ftime)


ggplot(data = fdf, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  facet_wrap(fsubs ~ ., ncol = 1)
```

The `tidyr` function `pivot_wider` allows us to create the shape of the data we need without explicit loops: create new columns `a` and `b` with values from `fcounts`. We do need to create a unique row id to make this work.

By the way, when I run your code the plots look different from what you posted in the question.

With this output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to create a visualization that would analyze all 4 variables. Got a `geom_histogram`

````
```{r}
fitem<-rep(rep(1:16,each=3),2)
fsubs<-factor(rep(rep(paste('sub',1:3,sep=''),16),2))
ftime<-factor(as.character(rep(c('a','b'),each=48)))
fcounts<-as.numeric(round(runif(96,1,10)))
fdf<-data.frame(fsubs,fitem,fcounts,ftime)

fdf_counts<-data.frame()
for (i in unique(fdf$fsubs)){
  fdf_counts<-append(fdf_counts,cbind(fdf%>%filter(fsubs==i,ftime=='a')%>%dplyr::select(fcounts),
                        fdf%>%filter(fsubs==i,ftime=='b')%>%dplyr::select(fcounts)))

fdf_counts<-data.frame(fdf_counts)
}


ggplot(data = fdf, mapping = aes(x = fdf$fsubs, y = fdf$fcounts, fill = fdf$fitem)) +               geom_bar(stat = "identity", position =     "dodge") + facet_grid(cols = vars(ftime))


```
````

[image]